# Using Multiple @XmlAnyElement in JAXB to manually handle </> Characters in Multiple Strings

Tags: xml, jaxb, sax

We are using JAXB to unmarshal pre-stored XML that can't be changed by us. Unfortunately, the pre-stored XML contains some HTML brackets, `< and >, without CDATA.`. For instance, we have to unmarshal this with JAXB (note there is no CDATA):

```
<Article>
  <ArticleTitle>Note the unescaped inner HTML (T<sub>3</sub>) in the title</ArticleTitle>
  <Abstract>
     <AbstractText>This is another element that has unescaped HTML: T<sub>3</sub>. </AbstractText>
  </Abstract>
</Article>
```

We need to preserve the HTML data above. JAXB chokes on these and gives us incorrect model values.

One solution that works is to use `@XmlAnyElement` and then implement a `DomHandler` (see below).

**But unfortunately only 1 @XmlAnyElement is allowed per class. If I add several, for Title & Abstract, only one of them works at  time.** So this solution only works for 1 field that has this problem. I've tried implementing an `XmlAdapter` (not a `DomHandler`) but the string already comes in truncated so I can't use that solution, only this one.

[Force jaxb unmarshaller to ignore html Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811351/force-jaxb-unmarshaller-to-ignore-html-tags)

```
@XmlAnyElement(value=AbstractTextHandler.class)
protected String abstractText=null;
```

then implement

```
public class AbstractTextHandler implements DomHandler<String, StreamResult> {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    private static final String START_TAG = "<Abstract>";
    private static final String END_TAG = "</Abstract>";

    private StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter(); 

    public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
    }

    public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
        String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
        int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(START_TAG) + START_TAG.length();
        int endIndex = xml.indexOf(END_TAG);
        String result = xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
        log.info("Processing.." + result);
        return result;
    }

    public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        try {
            String xml = START_TAG + n.trim() + END_TAG;
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This needs to work for multiple fields, but only 1 `@XmlAnyElement` is allowed.

Is there a way for us to use a SAX parser or something to handle the XML umarshalling ourselves, to avoid choking on these HTML brackets? Or is there an `@XmlAnyElement` workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As the doc indicates it, `@XmlAnyElement` is acting as a catch-**(ALL)** mechanism. That's the reason why only one occurrence is allowed.

Knowing that, you could may be refactor your Article JAXB bean as:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Article {

  @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
  protected List<Object> innerBeans;

}
```

This way, ArticleTitle and Abstract will be both automatically unmarshalled as JAXB beans into the "innerBeans" list.

Answer (score 0):

Handle *mixed content* via `mixed="true"` on the `xsd:complexType` declaration of the content models of `ArticleTitle` and `AbstractText` in the XSD.

Comment: We have no control over the XSD or the produced XML. The only thing we can do is read the final XML string.

Comment: What is the content model of `ArticleTitle` and `AbstractText` in the given XSD?  If it is not mixed, then how do you expect JAXB to know that those elements may have mixed content?  Have you considered providing JAXB with your own XSDs that actually reflect the reality of the XML you have?